# C++ DLL crashes when called from ActiveX DLL running under IIS with Multpile Users

Tags: c++, dll, iis-7, vb6, activex

I have a project where an ActiveX DLL written in VB6 is calling a C++ DLL. The ActiveX DLL is loaded through IIS 7 via an ASP "CreateObject" call.

Everything works perfectly when only a single web user is accessing the site, (tested through thousands of iterations). As soon as 2 or more concurrent users access the site, 1 or more of the user sessions will crash, (often with a 500 error)?

I suspected that this may be due to the C++ DLL not being properly thread-safe, so I rewrote it using a global mutex to restrict access. This had no effect.

To be honest since each instance of the VB6 ActiveX DLLs run in a single-threaded apartment I would have expected this not to be an issue anyway?

Can anyone shed some light onto what might be happening here? I suspect I don't really understand exactly what happens when IIS loads multiple instances of a VB6 ActiveX DLL.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX DLLs may be single threaded model or single threaded apartment model:
[image: Single Threaded]

[image: Apartment Threaded]

Did you write the ActiveX DLL? Can you determine its Threading Model?

Also, you might want to enable debugging to see if you can catch an the error in Visual Studio: http://www.falconwebtech.com/post/2010/12/28/Debugging-Classic-ASP-in-IIS7-and-VS2010.aspx

When debugging is enabled ASP is limited to processing one request at a time in a single threaded manner. So, if no error occurs while debugging, then the ActiveX DLL is most likely single threaded, not apartment threaded.

Also, do you know about the setting [AspExecuteInMTA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524510%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)? You might want to check that it isn't unintentionally set to true.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply.

> Did you write the ActiveX DLL? Can you determine its Threading Model?
I didn't write the ActiveX DLL but I do have access to the source code. It is using Apartment Threading.

Comment: > Also, you might want to enable debugging to see if you can catch an the error in Visual Studio: http://www.falconwebtech.com/post/2010/12/28/Debugging-Classic-ASP-in-IIS7-and-VS2010.aspx
> When debugging is enabled ASP is limited to processing one request at a time in a single threaded manner. So, if no error occurs while debugging, then the ActiveX DLL is most likely single threaded, not apartment threaded.
I have been running the VB6 debugger, but thus far have been unable to isolate this issue.

Comment: > Also, do you know about the setting AspExecuteInMTA? You might want to check that it isn't unintentionally set to true.
This is set to false. Might there be another IIS configuration setting at fault here?

Comment: Sorry, I dont know. But, the only other thing I can suggest is to try early binding instead of late binding on the object.

Comment: UPDATE: I've also re-written the C++ DLL to use Thread Local Storage... also without any change in the behaviour :(